# What's the difference between openjdk and cask java in brew?

Tags: java, gradle, homebrew

I installed `brew install gradle` and it installed `openjdk` as a dependency.

But it won't changed the default `java` as it still points to `HotSpot`.

I tried to make `openjdk` as default java, and Google told me that there's yet some another java package `brew install cask java`.

What's the difference between those, which version should I use with gradle and how to install it as a default java system-wide, with proper JAVA_HOME variables?

```
Mac OS 10.12.4

Homebrew 2.4.8

Gradle 6.5.1

(default java that was before installation)
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9

(default java that was before installation)
javac 11.0.1

(installed by brew as a dependency of gradle)
openjdk: stable 14.0.1
```

P.S.

And why `brew install gradle` decided to install additional `openjdk` when I already have HotSpot JDK (and javac) on my machine?

Comment: Could you give us your OS version, the version of your installed JVMs and the version of Gradle you installed?

Comment: @Patrick sure, please check the question I added it